# How can I write a script to summarise information from a multi-fasta file without using biopython?

Tags: python, fasta

I've an assignment for a bioinformatics class which is asking for a python script to do the following for a FASTA file with several protein sequences in it:

-Open a .fasta file specified by user input

-Print the header line (i.e. line beginning with ">")

-Print the first 10 amino acids and on the same line, report the number of amino acids in the sequence

After several hours of trying, I've only managed to get the header line and first 10 amino acids printed for the first sequence only. The for loop I've written doesn't seem to work beyond that (apologies if this is rubbish, I'm a complete beginner!)

```
input_file = open(input("\nPlease enter the name of a FASTA file (inlcuding the .fasta extension): "))
# Opens the file specified by the user
for line in input_file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line[0] == ">":
        header = line
        print("\nHeader:", header)  # prints the header line
        no_lines_searched = 0  # To stop loop after first line of sequence when printing first 10 AAs
        for i in input_file:
            if ">" not in i and no_lines_searched < 1:
                print("First ten amino acid residues: ", i[0:10], "# Amino acids: ")  # Prints the first 10 AAs
                no_lines_searched = no_lines_searched+1  # To stop loop after first line of sequence
```

I was trying to be clever and design the second loop such that it would return the first 10 amino acids of the sequence then stop until another sequence (denoted by ">") was encountered.

I was then planning to use a placeholder `%s` to somehow calculate the total sequence length for each sequence in the file, but can't seem to get past this point!

The output I get is as follows:

```
Header: >sp|P03378|ENV_HV1A2 Envelope glycoprotein gp160 OS=Human immunodeficiency virus type 1 group M subtype B (isolate ARV2/SF2) GN=env PE=3 SV=1
First ten amino acid residues:  MKVKGTRRNY # Amino acids:
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After spending most of today on this problem, I answered my own question. I was going about it in completely the wrong way. Here's the code I've used to achieve exactly what I was aiming for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
seq = ""  # seq is a variable used to store each line of sequence data as the loop below iterates.

ten_AAs = ''  # ten_AAs is a variable used to store the first ten amino acids of each sequence (it actually stores
# the first 10 AAs from each line of the sequence, but only the first 10 residues of each sequence are printed).

seq_count = 0  # seq_count is a variable used to track the total number of sequences in the file.

infile = input("\nPlease enter the name of a FASTA file (including the .fasta extension): ")
# Stores the file specified by the user in the variable, infile.

with open(infile, "r") as fasta:  # Opens the above file such that we do not need to call filename.close() at the end.
    print("\n")
    for line in fasta:  # Initiates a for loop to summarise the file: headers, first ten residues and sequence lengths.
        line = line.rstrip()  # Removes trailing newline characters.
        if line[0] == ">":  # Indicates the start of a new FASTA sequence and is a condition for printing summary data
            if seq != "":  # Second condition for printing summary data (see lines 28-30).
                print("Header: {0}\nFirst ten amino acids: {1} \tSequence length: {2} residues\n"
                      .format(header, ten_AAs[0:10], len(seq)))  # Placeholders for summary info.
            seq_count += 1  # Increases seq_count by one for each header encountered.
            header = line  # Stores the header line for printing.
            seq = ""  # Resets seq for each iteration.
            ten_AAs = ''  # Resets ten_AAs for each iteration.
        else:
            seq += line[:]  # Appends seq with the characters of the line if it is not a header (i.e. sequence data).
            ten_AAs += line[0:10]  # Appends ten_AAs with the first ten characters of the line if it is not a header.

# After reading all lines of one sequence, the loop encounters the next FASTA sequence, starting with a ">" character,
# but 'seq' is not blank. Therefore, both 'if' statements are now TRUE and all summary data for the first sequence
# (stored in 'header', 'ten_AAs' and 'seq') are printed as per lines 18-19.

print("Header: {0}\nFirst ten amino acids: {1} \tSequence length: {2} residues"
      .format(header, ten_AAs[0:10], len(seq)))
# The final sequence is not followed by another accession number; therefore, the summary data for the final sequence
# must be printed manually, outside of the loop.

print("\nThis multi-FASTA file contains", str(seq_count), "sequences.")
# For completeness' sake, reports the number of sequences in the multi-FASTA file.
```

And here's the output:

```
Please enter the name of a FASTA file (including the .fasta extension): multiprotein.fasta


Header: >1433G_HUMAN (P61981) 14-3-3 protein gamma (Protein kinase C inhibitor protein 1) (KCIP-1) [Homo sapiens]
First ten amino acids: VDREQLVQKA       Sequence length: 246 residues

Header: >ATP8_RAT (P11608) ATP synthase protein 8 (EC 3.6.3.14) (ATPase subunit 8) (A6L) (Chargerin II) [Rattus norvegicus]
First ten amino acids: MPQLDTSTWF       Sequence length: 67 residues

Header: >ALR_LISIN (Q92DC9) Alanine racemase (EC 5.1.1.1)
First ten amino acids: MVTGWHRPTW       Sequence length: 368 residues

Header: >CDCA4_HUMAN (Q9BXL8) Cell division cycle-associated protein 4 (Hematopoietic progenitor protein) [Homo sapiens]
First ten amino acids: MFARGLKRKC       Sequence length: 241 residues

This multi-FASTA file contains 4 sequences.
```